# Why does it appear that I apparently "do not have access to Command Line Tools" in ML?

Tags: xcode, command-line, macos, gcc

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion, and now `gcc`, `make`, `g++`, etc. are `not found` when trying to launch them in Terminal.

So I went to Xcode Preferences, Downloads, and clicked "Install" next to Command Line Tools.

It asked me for my Apple ID, which is weird and unnecessary, but I entered it anyway. Note that I am a registered Mac OS X and iOS developer (so I pay 2x $99 per year).

Much to my surprise, it tells me:

[image]

Um, what?! And why is it asking?

Comment: Typically, the tools are installed as part of the Xcode package in /Applications (or wherever else you have the app itself). If you run `xcode-select --print-path` does it show the correct location for your Xcode?

Comment: @bmike: yes, it shows `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` as expected. The command line tools actually seem to be in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`, can I just add that to my path? If so, why does Xcode say the Command Line Tools are an additional 115.1 MB?

Comment: I believe just the [essential tools are bundled now](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html) and the full set of command line tools are packaged separately. Also, there is this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools/9964905#9964905

Comment: @bmike: thanks, the stackoverflow answer worked. Still, I'd like somebody to answer the question as it stands. It's unacceptable if Apple really will officially require a special subscription just to get the tools.

Comment: Perfect - I don't think it's stupid or unacceptable, but I can see how many might feel that way. My guess is it's unintentional and due to a capacity or server side bug - but only time will tell if this is intended going forward.

Comment: @bmike: yeah, that's what I was thinking too -- but the fact that it now asks for your Apple ID seems to mean that some subscription will be required... AFAIK it didn't ask for anything before. Anyways, hopefully someone will know the answer to this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It thankfully seems that this was a temporary issue, probably due to the increased load on the Apple servers on Mountain Lion's release day.

I am now able to download the Command Line Tools as before so it seems the issue has gone away.

Alternatively, if you're still having problems, [this link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_simulator__resigned/cltools_mountainliondp2_march12.dmg) worked for me when the "Install" button in Xcode didn't.

Comment: Odd - I've installed Xcode on several Mountain Lion macs and not yet needed to enter any Apple ID other than in the App Store to start the download. Glad it's resolved as a temporary issue on the server side nonetheless.