# Can't install Xcode Command Line Tools on Mountain Lion

Tags: command-line, macos, xcode

I try to install the most recent (july 25) version of Command Line Tools (xcode44cltools_10_76938107a.dm), downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, but are stopped with the error message
"This package can only be installed on OS X 10.7
Install a version of the Command Line Tools that
supports OS X 10.8."

But I can't find any better version; if such exist why isn't it on the Developer site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I apparently "do not have access to Command Line Tools" in ML](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57395/i-apparently-do-not-have-access-to-command-line-tools-in-ml)

Comment: You can install them from inside XCode, see link above.

Answer (score 7):

**You can install the command line tools within XCode.**

Open XCode and navigate to the preferences.

> From here you have to go to the Downloads-Section. Here you can see
>   the ability to install the command line tools:

[image]

**EDIT:** I can see the right command line tools on the download-page from Apple:

[image]

Comment: 1. These are the command line tools I downloaded (as I said), and which wouldn't install (with the error message I mentioned). Have you verified that they work for you?

Comment: The download from ADC worked for me - but it didn't work from inside XCode.

Comment: 2. It is somewhat overblown to download 1.46 GB code for the purpose of installing a much smaller package, but I did several times after first installing Mountain Lion. Unfortunately, I can't get Xcode 4.4 to run properly either -- it grows to consume 20+ GB memory, leaving the system unresponsive.

Comment: Rene L: Could you really install the same version as I mentioned on OS X 10.8 (12A269)?

Comment: @kåre - Yes, after I first tried from inside XCode, and I got the error, I downloaded the Command Line Tools from ADC, and installed it without any problems.

Comment: @Kåre - you do know that there are a Lion and a Mountain Lion version, xcode44cltools_10_86938106a.dmg is for Mountain Lion

Comment: Yes, it is available now :-). Case closed.

Comment: It has been available under XCode 4.4 all the time (click and unfold, for all the XCode 'add-ons') :o)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find developer tools for your version of XCode is to click on the XCode menu, scroll down to "Open Developer Tool" then select "More Developer Tools..." which will take you to a website displaying the latest developer tools.

See my screenshot:

[image]